# Why is cursor.rowcount higher than the number of rows returned by cursor.fetchall in oracledb but not in cx_Oracle?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, oracle19c, python-oracledb

I am using the `oracledb` Python package to query a table in an Oracle database. When calling `cursor.fetchall()` (or `cursor.fetchmany()` in batches), the `cursor.rowcount` attribute is higher than the actual number of rows returned. However, this issue does *not* appear when using the same methods in `cx_Oracle`.

For example, when selecting all records from a table with 93 rows, `cursor.rowcount` is 96, whereas I would expect it to be 93 to match the number of rows in the table since [the docs describe it like this](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#Cursor.rowcount):

> This read-only attribute specifies the number of rows that have currently been fetched from the cursor (for select statements)...

##### Versions:

```
Python: 3.8.10
oracledb: 1.2.2
cx_Oracle: 8.3.0
Oracle database: 19c (19.12.0.0.0)
```

---

### Full example

Create example table:

```sql
-- Create a table of ids from 1 to 93
create table example_table as

select
  rownum as id
from
  dual
connect by rownum <= 93
```

Using both `cursor.fetchmany()` in batches and `cursor.fetchall()`:

```py
import oracledb

SQL = "select id from example_table"

un = 'abc'
pw = 'def'
cs = 'ghi'

with oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs) as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.prefetchrows = 0
        cursor.arraysize = 10
        cursor.execute(SQL)
        print(f"After execute() call: {cursor.rowcount=}")

        batch = 0
        while True:
            rows = cursor.fetchmany()
            if not rows:
                break
            print(f"Batch {batch}: {cursor.rowcount=}")
            batch += 1

        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        print(f"After fetchall() call: {cursor.rowcount=}")
```

Produces this:

```
After execute() call: cursor.rowcount=0
Batch 0: cursor.rowcount=20
Batch 1: cursor.rowcount=30
Batch 2: cursor.rowcount=40
Batch 3: cursor.rowcount=50
Batch 4: cursor.rowcount=60
Batch 5: cursor.rowcount=70
Batch 6: cursor.rowcount=80
Batch 7: cursor.rowcount=90
Batch 8: cursor.rowcount=100
Batch 9: cursor.rowcount=96
After fetchall() call: cursor.rowcount=96
```

Note that the final values are the same if just calling `fetchall()` (i.e. removing the `fetchmany()` calls):

```
After execute() call: cursor.rowcount=0
After fetchall() call: cursor.rowcount=96
```

The key point is that `cursor.rowcount` is 96, where I'd expect it to be 93. The interesting parts to me are:

1. After the first batch, `rowcount` is already 20 - I would have expected it to be 10 here
2. After batch 8, `rowcount` is 100 - it has 'overshot' the actual table row count - which seems to indicate `rowcount` does not necessarily reflect the number of rows *actually* fetched, but the number of rows *attempted* to be fetched, at least initially
3. After the final batch (and also after the `fetchall()` call), `rowcount` is 96 - I would expect it to be 93 here

   - From testing with other values for `arraysize`, it seems to follow the  pattern `r = t + (t mod a)` where `r = rowcount`, `t = total table rows`, and `a = arraysize`
   - To illustrate, another example on the same table using `arraysize = 20`:

   ```
   After execute() call: cursor.rowcount=0
   After fetchall() call: cursor.rowcount=106
   ```

---

### `cx_Oracle` comparison

Now testing using the same methods in `cx_Oracle` - the only lines changed being:

```
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"C:\oracle\instantclient_21_7")

with cx_Oracle.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs) as connection:
```

This behaves how I expected:

```
After execute() call: cursor.rowcount=0
Batch 0: cursor.rowcount=10
Batch 1: cursor.rowcount=20
Batch 2: cursor.rowcount=30
Batch 3: cursor.rowcount=40
Batch 4: cursor.rowcount=50
Batch 5: cursor.rowcount=60
Batch 6: cursor.rowcount=70
Batch 7: cursor.rowcount=80
Batch 8: cursor.rowcount=90
Batch 9: cursor.rowcount=93
After fetchall() call: cursor.rowcount=93
```

---

### Summary

I originally wondered if the issue might be caused by `cursor.prefetchrows`, which is why I set that to 0, but that had no effect.

I wonder if it is related to how [these methods are using `arraysize` to make reads to the database](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#Cursor.fetchall).

I'm still not sure what I'm missing here though. What is causing this behaviour, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Sounds wrong. Can you open an issue on python-oracledb? https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/issues and link back to this question? I'll take a look at it regardless, though!

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga thanks! Sure, I've opened an issue here and linked to this post: [https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/issues/147](https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/issues/147)